Trying to complete a mixed factorial anova and get this error code
This is the code:
noise_within_aov <- aov_ez(dv = "test_score",
    id = "participant",
    within = "noise",
    data = noise_test_mixed)
noise_within_aov

This is the error message

Error in as.data.frame.default(data) :
cannot coerce class ‘"afex_aov"’ to a data.frame

expecting a factorial anova

Why the C# tag?

If you look at the afex readme, it indicates you can use the afex::nice or anova() functions to have a summary of model outputs.
Another option would be to try base R's summary function, but this i just a guess since I haven't used this library.
Please include a minimal reproducible example in the future to help us recreate and debug your errors.
